# Is there a way to define how open graph images show on iOS message app?

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph

I’ve recently found out that you can have multiple `og:image` meta tags on a page. Unfortunately I am unable to understand if and how you can interfere with how it shows on iOS message app.

This Shopify website is able to show a mosaic of 3 pictures which is really nice: [hodinkee](https://shop.hodinkee.com/collections/tag-heuer/products/tag-heuer-carrera-160-years-montreal-limited-edition-cbk221c?variant=32474299891787).

I tried using three meta tags as they do and tried to change the image size to be the same as they use but without success. Any input is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting here the answer to my own question in case this could help others out.

The order in which you put the meta tags has it's importance for iOS. If the sharing tool of iOS first finds the meta `og:image` it will use that for the thumbnail, if it first finds `twitter:image` it will use that instead.

So the correct order for me to have the mosaic show up was to add my `og:image` tags first and then add the Twitter ones.